# Getting Column Names from my MySQL database table

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to get Column names from tables so I can dynamically recreate the tables on my website. The table name and database names are dynamic and are therefore stored in variables. My code

```
function getDBTbldata() {
    if (isset ( $_GET ['tbl'] )) {
        $dbName= $_GET['db'];
        $tblName = $_GET ['tbl'];
        echo "<h3> Using Table : $tblName  </h3>";
        $link = mysqli_connect ( '192.168.2.113', 'root', '',  $dbName );
        if (! $link) {
            die ( "Connection failed" . mysqli_errno ( $link ) );
        }
        $colqry = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = $dbName AND TABLE_NAME = $tblName";
        $col_names = mysqli_query ( $link, $colqry );
        var_dump($col_names);
        while ($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($col_names)){
            echo $column[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code gives me with the following error:

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

I've checked my Query for any syntax errors but I can't spot any obvious ones. Any help?

Comment: `echo $colqry` and run the sql outputted by echo in either in phpmyadmin or mysql workbench or command line interface by copying it from browser.

Comment: $colqry likely errored because the string values for the schema and table names were not in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $colqry` returned a query which I tested on phpmyadmin like suggested. There was indeed an error due to the variables not being qouted which I fixed and it works now. Thanks

```
 $colqry = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName' AND TABLE_NAME = '$tblName'";
```

Above how the Syntax should look like.